# Brahman (ब्रह्म) Tarapanam - meaning?

Tags: advaita, brahman

I am currently reading **Sadhanas From the Ribhu Gita by Swami Shantananda**. In chapter 5 (Page 34 of http://swamishantanandapurimaharaj.org/publications/Sadhanas-from-Ribhu-Gita.pdf), have come across the term Brahman (ब्रह्म) Tarapanam. I haven't come across this term before or find it's meaning.

Comment: The simple meaning of [brāhmaṇatarpaṇa](https://faculty.washington.edu/prem/mw/b.html) would be tarpaṇa (the feeding or satisfying) of Brāhmaṇa... can you link the exact verse where u read this so that the context can be known?

Comment: From Chapter 5. - A Fire sacrifice to please the Brahman or the self. "... I am a mass of bliss. I am the entire void. I am both the external and impermanent objects. This is Brahman Tarapanam. I am the infinite space of Consciousness. I am the Atman. I am always content with myself. I do not need anything else. This is Brahman Tarapanam. I am subtler than the space. I am totally non-existent-existent. I give light and reveal all objects. This is Brahman Tarapanam."

Comment: I can't find an online version but you can listen to the audio here: http://sanatanaudiobooks.blogspot.com/2013/08/sadhanas-from-ribhu-gita-english-ribhu.html

Comment: Okay.. I thought u meant Brahmin (ब्राह्मण)..edited the Q.. as the linked pdf's chapter title says it's "A fire sacrifice to please the Brahman or the Self"..